# Search method Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I made this method for a search method in ruby with a form.

I think, that this code can be simplify. What do u think ?

And I have an issue. When a user does not enter anything in the form, the results display all the tips in the database.

But when a user combines two searches, for example a keywords and a country, the result is all the tips that have the keywords as well as all the tips that have the country concerned. Except what I'm looking for is for the two criteria to be combined.

Search.rb

```
require 'pry'

class Search < ApplicationRecord

  def self.search(keywords, category_id,city,country)
    table_of_ids_country = []
    table_of_ids_city = []
    table_of_ids_title = []
    table_of_ids_cats = []
    two_searches_ids = []
    merged_table_of_tips_ids = []
    @results = []

    tips_by_country = Tip.where(["country like?",country]) if country.present?

    tips_by_city = Tip.where(["city like?",city]) if city.present?

    tips_by_keyword = Tip.where(["title LIKE?","%#{keywords}%"]) if keywords.present?

    tips_by_cat = Category.where(["id = :id",{id:category_id}]) if category_id.present?

    two_searches = Tip.where(["title LIKE?",keywords]) if keywords.present? && Category.where(["id = :id",{id:category_id}]) if category_id.present?

    if tips_by_country != nil
      tips_by_country.each do |tip|
        tip.id
        table_of_ids_country << tip.id
      end
    end

    if tips_by_city != nil
      tips_by_city.each do |tip|
        tip.id
        table_of_ids_city << tip.id
      end
    end

    if tips_by_keyword != nil
      tips_by_keyword.each do |tip|
        tip.id
        table_of_ids_title << tip.id
      end
    end

    if two_searches != nil
      two_searches.each do |tip|
        tip.id
        two_searches_ids << tip.id
      end
    end

    if tips_by_cat != nil
      Category.find(tips_by_cat[0].id).tips.each do |tip|
        table_of_ids_cats << tip.id
      end
    end

    merged_table_of_tips_ids = [table_of_ids_title, table_of_ids_cats,table_of_ids_city,table_of_ids_country,two_searches_ids].flatten

    merged_table_of_uniq_tips_ids = merged_table_of_tips_ids.uniq


    merged_table_of_uniq_tips_ids.each do |tip|
       result = Tip.find(tip)
       @results << result
       binding.pry
    end
    return @results
  end
end
```

searches_controller

```
require 'pry'
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.create(search_params)
    redirect_to @search
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @search = Search.search(@search.keywords, @search.category_id,@search.city,@search.country)
    #Permet d'envoyer les paramètres au model search et à les réutilisé dans la méthode self.search
  end

private

  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:keywords,:category_id,:id,:city,:country)
  end
end
```

my form :

```
<%=form_for @search do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :keywords, "Mots-clés" %>
            <%= f.text_field :keywords, class: "form-control", placeholder: "plongée, randonnée, temple..." %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :city, "Mots-clés" %>
            <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control", placeholder: "plongée, randonnée, temple..." %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :country, "Mots-clés" %>
            <%= f.text_field :country, class: "form-control", placeholder: "plongée, randonnée, temple..." %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :category_id, "Catégories" %><br>
            <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
            <%= f.submit "Rechercher", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
          <%end%>
```

Comment: You can try moving all the query to a `scope` for simplifying the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord

  def self.search(keywords, category_id,city,country)
    ids = if keywords.present? && category_id.present?
            Tip.keywords(keywords).pluck(:id) & Category.category_id(category_id).pluck(:id)
          elsif [keywords, category_id, city, country].any?(&:present?)
            Tip.country(country)
              .city(city)
              .keywords(keywords)
              .pluck(:id)
          else
            []
          end

    Tip.find(ids.uniq)
  end
end

class Category < ApplicationRecofd
  scope :category_id, ->(category_id) {
    where(["id = :id",{id:category_id}])
  }
end

class Tip < ApplicationRecord
  scope :country, ->(country) {
    where("country like?",country) if country.present?
  }

  scope :city, ->(city) {
    where("city like?",city) if city.present?
  }

  scope :keyword, ->(keywords) {
    tips = tips.where("title LIKE?","%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
  }
end
```

also notice I'm doing a union on category ids, so keep in mind

```
2.5.1 :002 > [1,2] && [2,3]
 => [2, 3] 
2.5.1 :003 > [1,2] & [2,3]
 => [2]
```